# Mouse event not reaching UIElement

Tags: c#, canvas, mouseevent, uielement, routedevent

I have a 6x8 grid of `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` objects. The top left canvas does not receive mouse events while all the others do. I tried `OnMouseMove` and `OnMouseClick` events.

A child object isn't handling the event because `System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper#GetChildrenCount()` doesn't show any children. I couldn't catch `PreviewOnMouseMove` either. Can there be some (perhaps transparent) control in front of my canvas that is taking precedence?

Comment: could you post the code/xaml in question? it would help us lots in helping you solve your problem! ;)

Comment: I know, I know. There are many controls being created here and there. My question would have been very bulky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Each of the `Canvas`es have `Adorner`s. According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx), adorners receive mouse events before the underlying UI element does. I set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of all my adorners to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you, Just set `Transparent` value to the `Background` property for the `Canvas`:

```
Background="Transparent"
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried for the Canvas only - but just for the record do we have any explanation as to why setting a backgrounds to transparent might help? EDIT: (It would be useful to know)